# Yii2 Controller post request is NULL

Tags: php, yii2

Can anyone tell why controller post in database is NULL ?
but in vardump have data

Controller

```
 $model = new Reg();

 $model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post());
 $model->save();
```

Model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title', 'article', 'fio','country', 'position','tel', 'email','cert'], 'required',  'message'=>'required'],
        [['title', 'article', 'fio','country', 'position','tel', 'email','cert'], 'string'],
        [['title', 'article'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

View

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model,'title')->textInput(['class'=>'header__enter__input','placeholder'=>''])->label(false) ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model,'article')->textInput(['class'=>'header__enter__input','placeholder'=>''])->label(false) ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model,'fio')->textInput(['class'=>'header__enter__input','placeholder'=>''])->label(false) ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model,'country')->textInput(['class'=>'header__enter__input','placeholder'=>''])->label(false) ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model,'position')->textInput(['class'=>'header__enter__input','placeholder'=>''])->label(false) ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model,'tel')->textInput(['class'=>'header__enter__input','placeholder'=>''])->label(false) ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model,'email')->textInput(['class'=>'header__enter__input','placeholder'=>''])->label(false) ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model,'cert')->textInput(['class'=>'header__enter__input','placeholder'=>''])->label(false) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Comment: Show your entire `model` class

Comment: show the output of `Yii::$app->request->post()`

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord insert data to db when model validate() returned true. If this error occured for model attributes validating and validate() method returned false post data wil not insert to db for view error you can use change the controller to this

```
 $model = new Reg();   

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->save()){   
        return $this->redirect(['index']);   
    }   

    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);   
}
```

and you can view errors in validate or not and fix this

Comment: dont know who up-voted this answer when using ActiveRecord models `$model->validate()` is always called when saving the data unless you call `$model->save(false)`, so you are calling the `validate()` twice technically, you only call `$model->validate()` in case you are using form model or your model is extended using `yii\base\Model`

Answer (score 0):

`$model->save(false);`

will save your data forcefully by skipping validation but it is bad practice,

use `$model->getErrors()` after save, It will return list of validation errors which prevent data from storing from database